# How to write a JPA query to find objects between two dates?

Tags: java, sql, spring, jpa

Here's my query

```
@Query(value = " SELECT * FROM account.statement where `date` between ?1 and ?2")
List<Statement> findAllByDate(String startDate, String endDate);
```

And this is the error message I get

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: unexpected char: '`' [ SELECT * FROM account.statement where `date` between ?1 and ?2]
```

The `date` is the column name. I want to retrieve a list of Statement objects between two dates. The dates in this case are LocalDate objects, like 2000-10-10. I tried using String and a LocalDate type in the parameters, still doesn't work.

I've searched everywhere, on stack overflow and baeldung. I am stuck

Comment: Remove " ` " around date

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Statement> findByDateBetween(Date start, Date end);
```

Comment: i tried, i get this expection
`
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 9 [ SELECT * FROM account.statement WHERE date BETWEEN ?1 and ?2]
`

Answer (score 1):

Turns out this was the correct implementation

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM account.statement WHERE date > ?1 AND date <= ?2",
nativeQuery = true)
List<Statement> findAllByDate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
```

Thank you my guy Thomas

Comment: no problemo sir

Answer (score 0):

You should be binding `LocalDate`, not `String`, to the placeholders:

```java
@Query(value = " SELECT * FROM account.statement WHERE date BETWEEN ?1 and ?2")
List<Statement> findAllByDate(LocalDate startDate, LocalDate endDate);
```

Comment: I get this issue now

Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: * near line 1, column 9 [ SELECT * FROM account.statement WHERE date BETWEEN ?1 and ?2]

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("select a from Statement a where a.startDate >= :startDate and a.endDate <= :enddate")
List<Statement> findAllByDate(
@Param("startDate") Date startDate,@Param("endDate") Date endDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

while using @Query might solve the problem, but you can also use JpaRepository in this case

1. First of all you need to add JpaRepository to your repository
   interface :

   extends JpaRepository<Statement, Long>
2. use this line and replcae Date with the date column name and use the appropriate type of date:

   List findByDateBetween(LocalDateTime to, LocalDateTime
   from);

exemple :

```
    @Repository 
public interface StatementRepository  extends JpaRepository<Statement, Long> {
     
     //where x.startDate between ?1 and ?2
     List<Statement> findByDateBetween(LocalDate to,LocalDate from);
     
     }
```

for more information you can see the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#reference)